Is there any way to change the ls colors for vterm?
Normally in my emacs config, I use doom-gruvbox. However, I want to use Dracula theme for my terminal -- namely v-term. I customized my .zshrc to reflect my desired changes, here are the relevant configurations:
autoload -U colors && colors
colors

# Set ls colors
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS="gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad"

alias ls='ls -G'

PS1='%F{#50FA7B}Marx%f %F{#8BE9FD}%1~%f %F{#FF79C6}$%f '


# Enable colors
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=(main cursor)
typeset -gA ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES
# Default groupings per, https://spec.draculatheme.com, try to logically separate
# possible ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES settings accordingly...?
#
# Italics not yet supported by zsh; potentially soon:
#    https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/432
#    https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg00678.html
# ... in hopes that they will, labelling accordingly with ,italic where appropriate
#
# Main highlighter styling: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/docs/highlighters/main.md
#
## General
### Diffs
### Markup
## Classes
## Comments
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[comment]='fg=#6272A4'
## Constants
## Entitites
## Functions/methods
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[alias]='fg=#50FA7B'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[suffix-alias]='fg=#50FA7B'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[global-alias]='fg=#50FA7B'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[function]='fg=#50FA7B'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=#50FA7B'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[precommand]='fg=#50FA7B,italic'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[autodirectory]='fg=#FFB86C,italic'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[single-hyphen-option]='fg=#FFB86C'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[double-hyphen-option]='fg=#FFB86C'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[back-quoted-argument]='fg=#BD93F9'
## Keywords
## Built ins
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[builtin]='fg=#8BE9FD'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[reserved-word]='fg=#8BE9FD'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[hashed-command]='fg=#8BE9FD'
## Punctuation
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[commandseparator]='fg=#FF79C6'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command-substitution-delimiter]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command-substitution-delimiter-unquoted]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[process-substitution-delimiter]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[back-quoted-argument-delimiter]='fg=#FF79C6'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[back-double-quoted-argument]='fg=#FF79C6'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[back-dollar-quoted-argument]='fg=#FF79C6'
## Serializable / Configuration Languages
## Storage
## Strings
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command-substitution-quoted]='fg=#F1FA8C'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command-substitution-delimiter-quoted]='fg=#F1FA8C'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[single-quoted-argument]='fg=#F1FA8C'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[single-quoted-argument-unclosed]='fg=#FF5555'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[double-quoted-argument]='fg=#F1FA8C'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[double-quoted-argument-unclosed]='fg=#FF5555'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[rc-quote]='fg=#F1FA8C'
## Variables
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[dollar-quoted-argument]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[dollar-quoted-argument-unclosed]='fg=#FF5555'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[dollar-double-quoted-argument]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[assign]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[named-fd]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[numeric-fd]='fg=#F8F8F2'
## No category relevant in spec
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[unknown-token]='fg=#FF5555'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path_pathseparator]='fg=#FF79C6'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path_prefix]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path_prefix_pathseparator]='fg=#FF79C6'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[globbing]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[history-expansion]='fg=#BD93F9'
#ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command-substitution]='fg=?'
#ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command-substitution-unquoted]='fg=?'
#ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[process-substitution]='fg=?'
#ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[arithmetic-expansion]='fg=?'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[back-quoted-argument-unclosed]='fg=#FF5555'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[redirection]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[arg0]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[default]='fg=#F8F8F2'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[cursor]='standout'

# Dracula theme main colors
# • Green: #50FA7B (used for functions and methods)
# • Blue: #8BE9FD (used for built-ins and reserved words)
# • Purple: #BD93F9 (used for back-quoted arguments and history expansion)
# • Pink: #FF79C6 (used for command separators and other punctuation)
# • Yellow: #F1FA8C (used for strings and command substitution)
# • White: #F8F8F2 (used for default text)

source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh



With this zsh config file, the colors of my prompt are set correctly (dracula-theme), however my ls colors -- namely the regular files, are still considered as default face (in vterm in emacs). So I figured that vterm/emacs must be taking over, so here is my emacs config:
      (use-package vterm
    :ensure t
    :config
    (defconst dracula-background "#282a36")
    (defconst dracula-current-line "#44475a")
    (defconst dracula-selection "#44475a")
    (defconst dracula-foreground "#f8f8f2")
    (defconst dracula-comment "#6272a4")
    (defconst dracula-cyan "#8be9fd")
    (defconst dracula-green "#50fa7b")
    (defconst dracula-orange "#ffb86c")
    (defconst dracula-pink "#ff79c6")
    (defconst dracula-purple "#bd93f9")
    (defconst dracula-red "#ff5555")
    (defconst dracula-yellow "#f1fa8c")

    (setq vterm-color-black   dracula-background)
    (setq vterm-color-red     dracula-red)
    (setq vterm-color-green   dracula-green)
    (setq vterm-color-yellow  dracula-yellow)
    (setq vterm-color-blue    dracula-purple)
    (setq vterm-color-magenta dracula-pink)
    (setq vterm-color-cyan    dracula-cyan)
    (setq vterm-color-white   dracula-foreground))

    ;; Ensure TERM is set correctly
    (setq vterm-term-environment-variable "xterm-256color")

      
     (custom-set-faces
    ;; Standard colors
    '(vterm-color-black ((t (:foreground "#282a36" :background "#282a36"))))
    '(vterm-color-red ((t (:foreground "#ff5555" :background "#ff5555"))))
    '(vterm-color-green ((t (:foreground "#50fa7b" :background "#50fa7b"))))
    '(vterm-color-yellow ((t (:foreground "#f1fa8c" :background "#f1fa8c"))))
    '(vterm-color-blue ((t (:foreground "#bd93f9" :background "#bd93f9"))))
    '(vterm-color-magenta ((t (:foreground "#ff79c6" :background "#ff79c6"))))
    '(vterm-color-cyan ((t (:foreground "#8be9fd" :background "#8be9fd"))))
    '(vterm-color-white ((t (:foreground "#f8f8f2" :background "#f8f8f2"))))

    ;; Bright colors
    '(vterm-color-bright-black ((t (:foreground "#6272a4" :background "#6272a4"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-red ((t (:foreground "#ff6e6e" :background "#ff6e6e"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-green ((t (:foreground "#69ff94" :background "#69ff94"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-yellow ((t (:foreground "#ffffa5" :background "#ffffa5"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-blue ((t (:foreground "#d6acff" :background "#d6acff"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-magenta ((t (:foreground "#ff92df" :background "#ff92df"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-cyan ((t (:foreground "#a4ffff" :background "#a4ffff"))))
    '(vterm-color-bright-white ((t (:foreground "#ffffff" :background "#ffffff")))))



I know that the custom-set-faces and setting the color is kinda unneeded, but I was trying anything. This was also before I learned that emacs was setting the default face, not actually using vterm-color-white. The last thing I tried was
  (face-remap-add-relative 'default :foreground "#f8f8f2")


which weirdly enough, worked for normal org mode buffers, but not for vterm buffers --
tested with ls command mostly. So I don't really know from where emacs is setting the color of the file names, or the color of the terminal output to the default face, for example with 'echo.' If someone could kindly point me in the right direction, that would be lovely.
Additional info:
running MacOS on M3 chip -- with GNU Emacs 29.2
I added a picture to see what I mean about the mismatch between dracula white in the prompt and default face in vterm.

